# NodeJS Cannot post /app/

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Im using nodejs with mongodb and expressjs. Whenever i go to change info on a test account (already signed up) via the change info panel, i get this error "Cannot POST /app/" here is the 'app.js' source code below.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app', ['ui.router'])
    .config(config)
    .run(run);

function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // default route
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'home/index.html',
            controller: 'Home.IndexController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            data: { activeTab: 'home' }
        })
        .state('account', {
            url: '/account',
            templateUrl: 'account/index.html',
            controller: 'Account.IndexController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            data: { activeTab: 'account' }
        });
}

function run($http, $rootScope, $window) {
    // add JWT token as default auth header
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + $window.jwtToken;

    // update active tab on state change
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        $rootScope.activeTab = toState.data.activeTab;
    });
}

// manually bootstrap angular after the JWT token is retrieved from the server
$(function () {
    // get JWT token from server
    $.get('/app/token', function (token) {
        window.jwtToken = token;

        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    });
  });
})();
```

Server.js

```
require('rootpath')();
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
var config = require('config.json');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({ secret: config.secret, resave: false, saveUninitialized: true }));

// use JWT auth to secure the api
app.use('/api', expressJwt({ secret: config.secret }).unless({ path: ['/api/users/authenticate', '/api/users/register'] }));

// routes
app.use('/login', require('./controllers/login.controller'));
app.use('/register', require('./controllers/register.controller'));
app.use('/app', require('./controllers/app.controller'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./controllers/api/users.controller'));

// make '/app' default route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    return res.redirect('/app');
});

// start server
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server listening at http://' + server.address().address + ':' + server.address().port);
});
```

app.controller.js

```
<code>
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// use session auth to secure the angular app files
router.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.path !== '/login' && !req.session.token) {
        return res.redirect('/login?returnUrl=' + encodeURIComponent('/app' + req.path));
    }

    next();
});

// make JWT token available to angular app
router.get('/token', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.session.token);
});

// serve angular app files from the '/app' route
router.use('/', express.static('app'));

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: what are the routes you have defined in node js?

Comment: We need to see the Node.js code not the Angular one

Comment: what do you mean by nodejs code ? as in the server.js ?

Comment: please show app.controller file in /controllers folder as well.

Comment: Done, anything else you need ?